# Как отобразить значения на колонках в диаграмме matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Пытаюсь выровнять значения на колонках инвертированной диаграммы, но не получается, с правой всё получилось, а вот как с левой быть не знаю

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

%matplotlib inline

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True, figsize=(9, 6))

plt.suptitle('Повозрастная диаграмма по годам')

axes[0].barh(male_female_df['years'], male_female_df['male'])
axes[0].axis(xmin = 60, xmax = 80)
axes[0].invert_xaxis()
axes[0].set(title='Мужчины')
rects_male = axes[0].patches
for rect in rects_male:
    # Get X and Y placement of label from rect
    x_value = rect.get_width()
    y_value = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2

    # Number of points between bar and label; change to your liking
    space = -130
    # Vertical alignment for positive values
    ha = 'right'

    # Use X value as label and format number
    label = '{:,.1f}'.format(x_value)

    # Create annotation
    plt.annotate(
        label,                      # Use `label` as label
        (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at bar end
        xytext=(space, 0),          # Horizontally shift label by `space`
        textcoords='offset points', # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
        va='center',                # Vertically center label
        ha=ha,                      # Horizontally align label differently for positive and negative values
        color = 'black') 

axes[1].barh(male_female_df['years'], male_female_df['female'], color='hotpink')
axes[1].axis(xmin = 60, xmax = 80)
axes[1].set(title='Женщины')
axes[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
rects_female = axes[1].patches
# Place a label for each bar
for rect in rects_female:
    # Get X and Y placement of label from rect
    x_value = rect.get_width()
    y_value = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2

    # Number of points between bar and label; change to your liking
    space = -30
    # Vertical alignment for positive values
    ha = 'left'

    # Use X value as label and format number
    label = '{:,.1f}'.format(x_value)

    # Create annotation
    plt.annotate(
        label,                      # Use `label` as label
        (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at bar end
        xytext=(space, 0),          # Horizontally shift label by `space`
        textcoords='offset points', # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
        va='center',                # Vertically center label
        ha=ha,                      # Horizontally align label differently for positive and negative values
        color = 'black') 

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.annotate` - ошибка. Аннотации нужно делать внутри осей:

Сделайте три правки в коде:

- `space = -130` -> `space = 30`
- `plt.annotate(` ->  `axes[0].annotate(`
- `plt.annotate(` ->  `axes[1].annotate(`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)